# Reading a line with various variable types in C#

Tags: c#, .net, input

I am trying to read a line that consists of: 1 char and 2 integers.

My code looks like this:

```
char userHint = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
        
string[] v = Console.ReadLine().Split();

int a, b;

a = int.Parse(v[0]);
b = int.Parse(v[1]);
```

I recieve error `System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'`.

Sample input char : 'O'
Sample input ints : 1 2

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to split your string and then convert the characters to integer.

This code does what you try to do.

```
char userHint = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

char[] v = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();

 int a, b;

 a = Int32.Parse(v[0].ToString());
 b = Int32.Parse(v[1].ToString());

 Console.WriteLine("a: "+ a);
 Console.WriteLine("b: "+ b);
```

We use `Console.ReadLine()` so when we press enter the program can wait for the next input

Instead of `string[]` we use `char[]` because we split the input using `ToCharArray()`.

And then parse.

Input:

```
3
78
```

Output:

```
a: 7
b: 8
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem can be solved by reading a char like so :

```
char userHint = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine()[0]);
```

And then read the two integers :

```
string[] v = Console.ReadLine().Split();

int a, b;

a = int.Parse(v[0]);
b = int.Parse(v[1]);
```